# The G-Man walking around in HL2

Tags: half-life-2

I've noticed the G-Man walking around in various areas in HL2 and the episodes...always just outside of the normal camera range unless if you really look at him.

I realize that this is just a bit of cinematic flair and Valve is playing around here a bit, but I'm curious...is there any way to interact with him?  Shoot or kill him even?

I'm currently about halfway through Episode 2 and just noticed him walking on a far-off catwalk.  I didn't have access to a weapon at that point but it kind of made me wonder.

Comment: He is also found in Half-Life 1. I believe he is present in all Half-Life games.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, he is never close enough to harm. He is immune to being shot, even if you reach him via noclip or other means.

[Source (including list of locations)](http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Gman#List_of_exact_in-game_locations)